# Can I get an absolute path from a network path in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there any way in a batch script to take a shared network path on my computer and get the absolute path to that directory?

Example:
I'm running a batch file on TESTBOX.  I know the "stuff" folder on TESTBOX is shared on the network.  Can I get the absolute path to "stuff"?  If "stuff" were in C:\stuff then I want this:

`Command = GETPATH \\TESTBOX\stuff`

`Result = C:\stuff`

Comment: Are you saying you want to know what drive the share is located on the server?

Comment: No server, just my local machine.  I'm sharing a folder with others and I want to know the absolute path of that folder.

Comment: Not understanding how you wouldn't already know what the path is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to ask wmi for the share information

```dos
wmic share where "name='stuff'" get path
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked exactly how I wanted it to!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any shared folders you have on your local computer can also be seen using the `NET SHARE` command.

```
H:\>net share

Share name   Resource                        Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C$           C:\                             Default share
IPC$                                         Remote IPC
ADMIN$       C:\windows                      Remote Admin
STUFF        C:\STUFF
The command completed successfully.
```

So if the share name is **stuff** you can extract the output of the **NET SHARE** command into a variable by encapsulating it in a FOR /F command.

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* delims= " %%G IN ('net share ^|find /I "stuff"') DO SET sharepath=%%H
```